# I am getting error while importing model in maya

Tags: maya, fbx

I bought a model in fbx form and I want to do some animation on that model . When I tried to import the model in Maya software I got an error:
  1.The imported scene has no initial binding position (Bind Pose) for the skin. The plug-in will compute one automatically. However, running the 'Go To Bind Pose' command may create unexpected results.
2. The plug-in does not support the following material types:
    Material  will be imported as a Phong material.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have missed to export the Bind Pose.

Export that along with the model and you will get your error fixed.

No default Bind Pose is assigned by default so you should export along with the model.

Try using baking method to export.

Comment: from where I can export . Someone already have export the model gave it to me ...... I need to import in Maya

Comment: You need to ask the person to re-export the Bind Pose along.
You may try getting Bind Post from some other project but the output may not be the same or you may get some other errors.

Comment: I think export using baking method will fix your second error